# проблема с Xpath

Tags: xpath

подскажите пожалуйста как правильно на Xpath Зацепить ссылку которая находиться за текст1

```html
<div class="wrap">
<span >Текст1'</span>
<a  href="http://............">текст2 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Самый простой вариант: `//div[@class="wrap"]/a` но он просто берет `a` внутри `div.wrap`

Answer (score 0):

Вот так: `//span['Текст1']/following::a`